# Can't find valueChanged in qTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have QTimeEdit element. I want to cennect it to handler function. According to QT Docs it should have `valueChanged` signal but

```
In: type(self.time_mode_calendar_wake_1)
Out: <class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTimeEdit'>
In: self.time_mode_calendar_wake_1.valueChanged.connect(self.set_data)
Out: AttributeError: 'QTimeEdit' object has no attribute 'valueChanged'
```

Is there another signal for this?

Comment: There are `dateChanged`, `timeChanged` and `dateTimeChanged` signals according to [QT docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimeedit-members.html). I can't see the `valueChanged`. Perhaps the docs you are looking is outdated?

Comment: Yeah, it was an old one. Thanks